# Не работает авто-путь vscode в javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, path, intellisense

В редакторе Vscode не работает Авто заполнение пути в javascript файлах.
P.S. Система: Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в значении false этого параметра:
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,